# How to have multiple patterns for lint-staged?

Tags: lint, husky, lint-staged

I had it match on .rb and .js files for instance.

e.g. `**/*.{js,rb}`

And wanted to also match on `Gemfile` and `Rakefile` for instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the solution was to recursively use `{}`, e.g.

```json
  "lint-staged": {
    "{Gemfile,Rakefile,**/*.{js,rb,rake,ru}}": [
      "./node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js --write"
    ],
    "**/*.js": [
      "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js"
    ],
    "{Gemfile,Rakefile,**/*.{rb,rake,ru}}": [
      "bundle exec rubocop -a"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: It's a shame that neither `lint-staged` nor `micromatch` docs are clear about this -- at least I only found a proper solution in your answer. Thanks!